# Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, function

I have a simple piece of Javascript code and I get this Error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined (anonymous function)

The code is as below -

```
    function xyz(i){
    ....
    ....

    if(i==5) {  // do something }
    else {
      i=i+1;
    setTimeout("xyz(i)",10)

    }


   xyz(1);
```

Can someone please help me ?  Do I need to declare 'i' somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the `setTimeout` function. Try this, instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    xyz(i);
},10)
```

Always choose an anonymous function instead of a "stringed function"